# Using VB6 + WSH with Windows Compression

Tags: windows, vb6, compression, wsh

Having trouble with WSH and Windows Compression.

My goal is to be able to zip up files (not folders, but individual files from various locations, which I have stored in an array) using the built-in Windows Compression. I am using VB6.

**Here is my routine (vb6 code):**

```
Dim objShell
Dim objFolder
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
Set objFolder = objShell.namespace(savePath & "\export.zip")
' --
' loop through array holding files to zip
For i = 0 To filePointer
  objFolder.CopyHere (filesToZip(i))
Next
' --
Set objShell = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
```

It works, but issues arise when there are more than a few files. **I start getting errors from Windows** (presumably, its calling the compression too fast, and the zip file is locked). I **cant seem to figure out how to WAIT until the COPYHERE function completes** before calling the next one to avoid issues.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks -

Comment: Is this Visual Basic or VBScript? (Visual Basic != VBScript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve that sort of synchronization by checking the file count in your target ZIP folder before proceeding to the next loop iteration (as suggested [here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/windowsxpzip.htm) and [here](http://www.vistax64.com/powershell/176725-wait-file-copy.html)):

```
For i = 0 To filePointer
  objFolder.CopyHere filesToZip(i)

  Do Until objFolder.Items.Count = i+1
    WScript.Sleep 100
  Loop
Next
```

Comment: Helen- works on my single-core PC. On my quad-core, it doesn't. Sound strange? Anything I can do for that (maybe the multiple cores throws off the logic)? Thanks.

Comment: @OneNerd: Do you get Windows errors or VBScript runtime errors? If the latter, which error do you get, on which line etc?

Comment: well, it takes about 1 minute for each file to zip - its like its hanging or something. Not sure - I will tinker some more - gave you a vote up, and if I can get it to work, will mark as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: wound up going another way, but yours did work on my single-core processor, so marking as accepted. thanks Helen!